# Should I bring up company's past when interviewing?

Tags: interviewing, united-states, bankruptcy

Strangest thing happened. A company that called me the other day to schedule an interview is in the process of getting out of chapter 13 bankruptcy. I am not sure whether to bring this up during the interview. At the same time, I feel it's important for me to know the reasons so that to prepare to either get laid off, or the company going under.

Comment: Why would you knowingly take an unstable job?

Comment: @Paparazzi I assume that's can't declare chapter 11 bankruptcy again.  (CH13 is personal debt restructuring not the corporate equivalent.)  If the restructuring plan fails they're always subject to being liquidated under chapter 7.

Comment: I plan on working for the company for a max of a year. Fresh out of college and need the experience. It's an electric company that bought out another and than filed chapter 13 on the company they bought. Is this something that I should bring up? As they say `A bird in the hand is worth more than two in the bush` from the employ reviews I've read on [GlassDoor](Glassdoor.com), they are not a very diverse company. It's what you call a `good ole boys` type of company. Plus they have a very high turnover rate.

Comment: Of course if I like the company's culture, managers, work-life etc..I will stay. I'm basing my `one year` on the employee reviews about the company.

Comment: I just found out the company filed `Chapter 11` bankruptcy not chapter 13 and was in debt of more than 40 billion. Ouch...

Comment: @Paparazzi AFAIK unlike with lenders and suppliers, there's no such tiering among ordinary employees seeking back pay in a corporate bankruptcy and everyone would be in the same can the liquidator sell off enough assets to make our paychecks good bucket.  The only split is that the first ~$13k of back pay is prioritized near the top of unsecured creditors (secured credit is debt backed by collateral eg a loan to buy a car or building).  http://thismatter.com/money/credit/bankruptcy/priorities.htm

Comment: @Paparazzi that order is in chapter 7 not chapter 11 which would be a new filing not a continuation of the current chapter 11 process.  The no wages after the point of filing constraint is because from the point of filing for CH7 the company ceases all activities not related to winding the company down (which fall under administrative expenses).

Comment: `UPDATE:` I asked about the bankruptcy during the interview and was told its parent company filed for chapter 11 and the company I applied for split from its parent company. I didn't take the job. They  didn't list that I would start working in JULY of 2017 (which they didn't list in the job description) and that they would want a two year commitment.....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I am not sure whether to bring this up during the interview. At the
>   same time, I feel it's important for me to know the reasons so that to
>   prepare to either get laid off, or the company going under.

It makes complete sense to talk about the financial stability of the company. Most likely that is going to have a big impact on your decision to accept or decline any offer.

Remember that when interviewing, not only are they trying to judge your fit within the company, but you must also be judging the company's fit in your career.

You must ask about anything that is important to you - culture, expectations, management style, opportunities, etc, etc. And for most people, the company's financial viability is critical.

Do some research first. Often, you can search and learn why the company declared bankruptcy, how they are getting out of it, and at least some views on what the company will look like on the other side of bankruptcy. Then you can ask more questions about that during the interview. You might even seek out and discuss the company with former employees, if you can find some.

You want to learn how this past bankruptcy affects the company's prospects and future. And most important you want to learn how this might impact you.

I've not interviewed at companies that had declared bankruptcy, but I have interviewed at companies who had recent layoffs. I wanted to learn exactly what I was getting into and exactly what the expectations on me would be coming into a situation that had an unfortunate past. That let me make the right decision for myself.

Comment: Thanks Joe, I think I'll probably pass on this company. Too many red flags...

Comment: +1 Very good advice.  Doing a bit of research to tell you what got the company into chapter 11, how they are addressing it, and what there goals are, and what the current vector is are all important.  If there was a turnover at the top, and new leadership has a reputation for saving lost companies, than it would be good, if not.... very risky.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't dismiss it out of hand, although obviously joining a company in financial distress needs caution and a good understanding of what you're getting in to.

There can be good opportunities in a company undergoing major restructuring, and I had a very positive experience in this sort of environment. The department I joined was coming out of a very tough place - morale was very low at first, as a lot of people had been laid off - but many things that previously might have been set in stone were now open for discussion, both in terms of new business operations and new ways of working, and I was able to use my experience to influence and direct much more easily than I might have been able to in a more stable environment where the views of a brand-new, mid-level guy didn't count for much. I jumped right in, got to lead up some big recovery projects, and from the point of view of my career it was the best job I've had.

So i'd look to do detailed research on how the company and how it came to bankruptcy, and then use the "any questions" section of the interview to really understand their roadmap for rebuilding. Do they have a plan to turn the company around, is financing an ongoing issue, do they have leadership ability to execute, are they confident that they've solved the underlying issues? Questions like that, although obviously phrase them in a positive, open way. They should be accommodating, as it is a two-way process and they should realize that they've got a tough job to recruit in their circumstances too.

If you don't feel confident in the answers then pass, of course, but it's worth taking a look before dismissing it.